# Understanding a line through a passage

Tags: british-english, understanding

What this line means: That’s what I always you see?

> (Edward canes Anna once)
>
> Edward: *One. That’s what I always you see? I think it’s fairer you see to
>   count aloud. So that the boy knows what to expect. And to judge the gap
>   between – too long prolongs the experience but too quickly – you see?*
>
> Maureen: *You’ve broken the skin.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need more context to understand what exactly is going on in this scene, as it's confusing whether the caning is punishment or something else.  Also Edward refers to Anna as "the boy" which does not seem to make sense.

In any case, the sentence is missing a key word.  It would normally be:

> That's what I always **do**, you see?

I guess the writer left out the word to create some kind of dramatic effect, or as a cue to tell the actors how to say the line.  Usually there would be some kind of a pause before "you see", where a native English speaker would automatically fill in any missing words.

Comment: Exactly, Edward Caned boys in the past and now he is caning Anna (Edward's daughter)

Comment: @ShahruzRaad  Given it's from a play called "The Cane" I understand there's a lot of reference to using the cane as punishment.  It's just not clear how this fits in with the writer's overall *intention*, as corporal punishment like this is an uncomfortable subject.